# Is spreading arms foul

Tags: rules, basketball, nba

Is spreading arms wide and preventing the other team player behind you to move a foul? Is that some kind of illegal screen?

Comment: Welcome to Sports exchange. It appears that you have not done enough research towards this question. Please let us know what you've found

Comment: What's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, extending your arms while setting a screen is classified as an illegal screen.

http://videorulebook.nba.com/archive/illegal-screen-pickn-roll-screener-extends-arms-2/